# Determinant of Matrix with 1st row all ones.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices

> Suppose we have a matrix with first row consisting of ones, is there any way out instead of direct Laplace expansion to find the determinant of such matrices?

$$
\left(
\begin{matrix}
1 & 1 & \cdots & 1\\
a_{21} & a_{22} & \cdots & a_{2n}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
a_{n1} & a_{n2} & \cdots & a_{nn}
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

Comment: It is not clear what kind of answer do you want. Is "no, there isn't  any way out?" a good answer?

Comment: @JCAA Is there a elegant way to compute the determinant?

Comment: Subtracting the first column from other columns and expanding along the first row is "elegant enough" for me. There is no way you can avoid finding the determinant of a $(n-1)\times (n-1)$ matrix of general form.